# spring boot i text errror

Tags: spring-boot, itext

hi guys I have an existing pdf file that contain facture body I want to add text to this facture, I made a testing code to test how it works, but the code I wrote delete my original file and as a result the added text

```
private static final String FILE_PATH_NAME = "./src/main/resources/educart.pdf";
public void exportpdf(facture fact) {
    Document document = new Document();

    try {

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_PATH_NAME)));

        //open
        document.open();

        // Paragraph 1 ->
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a paragraph 1",
                FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18, Font.BOLDITALIC));

        document.add(p);

        // Paragraph 2 ->
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
        p2.add("This is a paragraph 2");
        p2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        document.add(p2);

        // Paragraph 3 ->
        Font f = new Font();
        f.setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        f.setSize(30);
        f.setColor(255, 0, 0);

        Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("This is a paragraph 3", f);
        p3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        document.add(p3);

        // Paragraph 4 ->
        Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph("Grokonez",
                FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 250, Font.BOLDITALIC));
        document.add(p4);

        // Finish task ->
        document.close();

        System.out.println("Finish!");

    } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

orignal pdf file

[image]

result

[image]

Comment: Your code does not read the existing PDF but only replaces it. You could have recognized this before running it by it only accessing the file using a `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: But also the whole `Document` / `PdfWriter` architecture in itext 5 and before is only for creating new pdfs. If you want to manipulate existing pdfs with itext 5, look for examples based on a `PdfReader` / `PdfStamper` architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PdfReader pdfReader =
                    new PdfReader("./src/main/resources/educart.pdf");
            //Create PdfStamper instance.
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, out);
```